# Need advice for my java if-statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

i wanna be able to use an if-statment like this:

```
int price = 60;
if (pizza.equals("string1","string2","string3")) { 
    int price2 = 10;
    System.out.println("You want " + pizza + " and it will cost " + price + price2  +" :-");
}
else if (pizza.equals("string1","string2") {
}
```

If my pizza that i type in is called string1, string2 or string3 then i want to get an int value and a variable called price2 and then add that to price (price + price2) somehow.

Comment: Sorry for a bad asked and not a good-looking question, my first time here :)

Comment: Use the OR logical operator (`||`): `if(pizza.equals("string1") || pizza.equals("string2") || pizza.equals("string3")) {...}`

Comment: You should use a switch-case statement instead (assuming Java7 or above). Please also document the intentional case fall through.

Comment: Or use a collection and `contains(pizza)`.

Comment: ty guys, just one little thing, can i make a int variable if pizza equals one of the strings?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't valid Java.  You can't just make up stuff and hope.   The compiler will tell you.

You can do something like this:

```
private Map<String, Integer> prices = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put("cheese", 10);
    put("pepperoni", 15);
    put("five meat", 20);
}};

public int getPrice(String pizzaOrder) { 
    int price = 0;
    if ((pizzaOrder != null) && prices.keySet().contains(pizzaOrder)) {
        price = prices.get(pizzaOrder);
    }
    return price;
}
```

A design like this is easier to test, more flexible, and better encapsulated.

Comment: Actually I thought that this is what most programmers do - making stuff up and hope it will work :-D

Comment: Fair enough.  8)  Compiler is the one exception - gotta speak the language.  No slang; no making up your own dialect.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three basic ways to do it:

1) Use OR in your `if` statements:

```
if (pizza.equals("pizza1") || pizza.equals("pizza2") || ...)
```

2) Create a `switch` statement:

```
switch(pizza) {
    case "pizza1":
    case "pizza2":
        return 10;
    case "pizza3":
        return 20;
    case "pizza4":
        return 15;        
}
```

3) Create a `Map<String, Integer>` storing the price of each pizza:

```
Map<String, Integer> prices = new HashMap<>();
prices.put("pizza1", 10);
prices.put("pizza2", 15);
prices.put("pizza3", 500); // Expensive pizza

int price = prices.get(pizza);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use of switch case statement (Java 7, and be sure that `pizza` is not null).

```
switch (Objects.requireNonNull(pizza, "pizza")) {
  "string1": 
  "string2":
  "string3":
    ...
  break;
  "string4": 
  "string5":
    ...
  break;
}
```

Or you can use:

```
if (Arrays.asList("pizza1", "pizza2", "pizza3").contains(pizza)) {
  ...
} else if (Arrays.asList("pizza3", "pizza4").contains(pizza)) {
  ...
}
```

It depends on your need, and the asList could be probably be refactored to constant, using an immutable set (such as `Collections.unmodifiableSet`).

[edit] since someone though of enum, you can also do that :

```
enum Pizza {
  pizza1(10),
  pizza2(10),
  pizza3(0),
  pizza4(0);

  private final int additionalPrice;
  private Pizza(final int additionalPrice) {
    this.additionalPrice = additionalPrice;
  } 
  public int getAdditionalPrice() {return this.additionalPrice; }
}
```

And later in your code:

```
String pizzaAsString = "pizza1"; // this is the variable "pizza" in your original code
Pizza pizza = Pizza.valueOf(pizzaAsString);
int price = 60 + pizza.getAdditionalPrice();
```

Enum are better in some case (this one).

Answer (score 0):

A bit expanded version of switch-case:

```
int price = 60, price2 = 0;
switch (pizza) {
  case "string3":
    price2 = 10;
    //intentionally no break.
  case "string1"://intentionally no break
  case "string2":
    System.out.println("You want " + pizza + " and it will cost " + (price + price2)  +" :-");
    break;
  default: throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong string for pizza: " + pizza);
}
```

I probably would use enums though instead of Strings though.